# Get XML map from file and export new data to XML - does not work due to errors

Tags: xml, xsd, converters, xsd-validation

I tried to find what is wrong. I received the XML code without XSD. I need to export excel data to XML and use the map from XML file I received. But when I import the data, these data are not in the same lines and after I´m unable to export it to XML.
I will be happy for any help.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LxERP>
    <Firm>
        <Contracts>
            <Contract>
                <ContractName>CA-Fleet</ContractName>
                <Asset ClientID="1FA6P">
                    <AssetName>527378 6359</AssetName>
                    <AssetSerialNumber>G6359</AssetSerialNumber>
                    <ClientNumber>527</ClientNumber>
                    <CodeAssetCategoryID>Equipment</CodeAssetCategoryID>
                    <CodeAssetGroupID>Fleet</CodeAssetGroupID>
                    <CCC_FleetStatus>Active</CCC_FleetStatus>
                    <CodeAssetOperationStatusID>Active</CodeAssetOperationStatusID>
                    <CodeAssetTypeID>P</CodeAssetTypeID>
                    <FinancialContractID>CA-Fleet</FinancialContractID>
                    <Make>FORD</Make>
                    <ModelNumber>Fudn</ModelNumber>
                    <CCC_LeaseVendor>Don</CCC_LeaseVendor>
                    <CCC_ModelYear>2016</CCC_ModelYear>
                    <CCC_CustomerReference/>
                    <CCC_Equip_AP_Coding>3942006206</CCC_Equip_AP_Coding>
                    <CCC_DriverAddress>65eet</CCC_DriverAddress>
                    <CCC_DriverCity>Lo</CCC_DriverCity>
                    <CCC_DriverStateProvince>ON</CCC_DriverStateProvince>
                    <CCC_DriverZipPostalCode>R2</CCC_DriverZipPostalCode>
                    <CCC_DriverEmailAddress>othy</CCC_DriverEmailAddress>
                    <CCC_DriverFirstName>Tim</CCC_DriverFirstName>
                    <CCC_DriverLastName>Wil</CCC_DriverLastName>
                    <CCC_DriverMiddleName/>
                    <CCC_FleetBusinessUnit>ARC</CCC_FleetBusinessUnit>
                    <CCC_FleetClientAssetID/>
                    <CCC_FleetUseType>DRIER</CCC_FleetUseType>
                    <DispositionDate/>
                    <AssetSalePrice>0.000</AssetSalePrice>
                    <InServiceDate>07/15/2015</InServiceDate>
                </Asset>
              <!-- Removed one '</Asset>' tag here -->
            </Contract>
        </Contracts>
    </Firm>
</LxERP>
```

XSD code generated:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="LxERP">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Firm">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Contracts">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Contract">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ContractName"/>
                      <xs:element name="Asset">
                        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="AssetName" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="AssetSerialNumber" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="ClientNumber" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CodeAssetCategoryID" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CodeAssetGroupID" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_FleetStatus" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CodeAssetOperationStatusID" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CodeAssetTypeID" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="FinancialContractID" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Make" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ModelNumber" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_LeaseVendor" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="CCC_ModelYear" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_CustomerReference" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:long" name="CCC_Equip_AP_Coding" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverAddress" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverCity" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverStateProvince" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverZipPostalCode" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverEmailAddress" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverFirstName" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverLastName" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_DriverMiddleName" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_FleetBusinessUnit" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_FleetClientAssetID" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CCC_FleetUseType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DispositionDate" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:float" name="AssetSalePrice" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="InServiceDate" minOccurs="0"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ClientID" use="optional"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: I formatted the XML and removed one tag from it to make it well-formed. Maybe this changes something.